# Phpspreadsheet COUNTIFS formula not calculated

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpspreadsheet

I create Excel export feature on my web with phpspreadsheet and using COUNTIFS formula in it. When the output is created, the cell with `countifs` formula is not calculated automatically. It needs to be clicked and press enter to calculate or by press ctrl + alt + f9. I am using Ms. Excel 2010.

I already set Excel formula setting to automatic

I tried to set: `$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(true);`

I tried using Excel 2007, but the problem still occurs.

I tried using my Android phone and open the Excel file with google spreadsheet, and the problem does not occur:

```
$sheet->setCellValue('C'. ($dtbl2 + 0) ,'=COUNTIFS(G'.$i_awal.':G'.$i_akhir.',"Persiapan",H'.$i_awal.':H'.$i_akhir.',">200000000",H'.$i_awal.':H'.$i_akhir.',"<=2500000000")');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('php://output');
```

I expect the formula to be calculated automatically

Comment: Use double-quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now it's worked, just use double quotes as people suggested and add some back slash before double quotes on string conditional

```
$sheet->setCellValue("C". ($dtbl2 + 0) ,"=COUNTIFS(G".$i_awal.":G".$i_akhir.",\"Persiapan\",H".$i_awal.":H".$i_akhir.",\">200000000\",H".$i_awal.":H".$i_akhir.",\"<=2500000000\")");

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Modify your code like this:**

```
$sheet->setCellValue("C". ($dtbl2 + 0) ,"=COUNTIFS(G".$i_awal.":G".$i_akhir.",'Persiapan',H".$i_awal.":H".$i_akhir.",'>200000000',H".$i_awal.":H".$i_akhir.",'<=2500000000')");

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('php://output');
```